# How to get object ID in array of object using axios GET method?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am a coding boot camp student and currently learning the axios method.

Using the axios.get function, I would like to be able to dynamically pull by the object ID using forms. This is my my current JS code, at the moment it is pulling all the array of objects from the API.

This is the snip-it of the array of objects from the API.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoEBx.jpg)

The HTML form where the object id is to be entered is.

```
            <form name = "axiosget">
            <input type ="text" id ="id" placeholder="Get Id"/>
            <button>Submit</button>

        </form>
```

And this is my axios.get code with the api "https://api.sample.io/todo"

```
const axiosGet =document.axiosget;
```

axiosGet.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
event.preventDefault()

```
const axiosGetId = {
    id: axiosGet.id.value
}

axios.get("https://api.sample.io/todo", axiosGetId)
.then((response) => console.log(response.data))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));



})
```

My POST works with suing this method. This is the HTML forms for the POST

```
   <form name = "newpost">
        <input name ="title" placeholder="Title"/>
        <input name ="description" placeholder="Description"/>
        <input name="imgUrl" placeholder="Image Url"/>
        <button>Submit</button>

    </form>
```

and this is the js code

```
const newPost =document.newpost;
```

newPost.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
event.preventDefault()

```
const newPostItem = {
    title: newPost.title.value,
    description: newPost.description.value,
    imgUrl: newPost.imgUrl.value,

 
};

axios.post("https://api.sample.io/todo", newPostItem)
.then((response) => console.log(response.data))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a REST API you should simply GET your "number 1" post with a simple /todo/1 route, so you can do a

```js
const axiosGetId = {
    id: axiosGet.id.value
}

axios.get(`https://api.sample.io/todo/${axiosGetId}`)
.then((response) => console.log(response.data))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

or concatene the id at the end of the route "https://api.sample.io/todo/" + axiosGetId

or pass it as a get value to the server with "https://api.sample.io/todo?id=1"

the difference with your POST method is that you don't send the ID when you save your resource, because the server does it for you and decides which ID will be your new todo

Comment: you are welcome, also note that the api should actually be like api.com/todos with a plural because a get on /todos should send you a collection of toto, and a get on /todos/32 should send you the todo ID 32

if you have more questions feel free to ask and also please mark this answer as the good one :D <3

Answer (score 0):

Check endpoint api, maybe you can add query parametr in request like this?

```
axios.get("https://api.sample.io/todo/123")
or
axios.get("https://api.sample.io/todo?id=123")
or
axios.get("https://api.sample.io/todo?_id=123")
```

Comment: This did not work, since the API end out is static. I would have to hardcode it directly in the body instead of it being entered at in a forms. My solution was using a concatenate method to allow a dynamic function. axios.get("https://api.sample.io/todo/" + axiosGetId.id).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).